# Delete the character and numbers from partiular position in comma delimeted file in unix

Tags: linux, csv

I want to delete the characters and numbers only from particular position from comma delimited file in unix.

My data like this

```
jagan1,*,*,*,*,*,W,24,25,26
jagan2,*,*,*,*,*,1,24,25,26
jagan3,*,*,*,*,*,*,24,25,26
jagan4,*,*,*,*,*,P,24,25,26
jagan5,*,*,*,*,*,*,24,25,26
```

In seventh position I want keep only *, if any number and any character is there I want to delete the complete line.

output like this

```
jagan3,*,*,*,*,*,*,24,25,26
jagan5,*,*,*,*,*,*,24,25,26
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply with **`awk`** script:

```
$ awk -F, '$7 == "*"' file.csv
jagan3,*,*,*,*,*,*,24,25,26
jagan5,*,*,*,*,*,*,24,25,26
```

---

- `-F,` - set `,` (comma) as input field separator
- `'$7 == "*"'`  - considers only lines which 7th field is equal to `*`

---

To remove the *unneeded* lines use the following **`sed`** approach:

```
$ sed -Ei '/^([^,]+,){6}[^*],/d' file.csv
```

Comment: I don't want display, I want remove from my text file

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @user378671, see my update

Comment: Thanks a lot Roman. Its working fine

Answer (score 1):

With [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference.html), using the `-I` option to edit the file in place:

```
mlr -I --csv --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output filter '$7 == "*"' file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

This attempt:

```
sed -i -Ee 's/^.*,[a-zA-Z0-9]*,[0-9]{2},[0-9]{2},[0-9]{2}$//' file && sed -i '/^$/d' file
```

---

Capture a string that has the format `...,<number or character>,<two numbers>,<two numbers>,<two numbers><end of line>` and delete.

---

Delete blank lines

```
'/^$/d'
```

Answer (score 0):

And the `grep` method:

```
$ egrep '^([^,]*,){6}\*,' file.txt 
jagan3,*,*,*,*,*,*,24,25,26
jagan5,*,*,*,*,*,*,24,25,26
```

`^` ... match the null string, but only at beginning of line

`([^,]*,){6}` ... match exactly 6 occurrences of arbitrary text followed by comma

`\*,` ... match a literal asterisk followed by a comma

So to rewrite your file, retaining only those lines:

```
$ egrep '^([^,]*,){6}\*,.*' file.csv > $$; mv $$ file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

In `in.txt` is your input file and you want to copy the lines with an asterisk in the seventh column to the file `out.txt`, you can use the following grep command:

```
grep -E '^(([[:alnum:]]+|[*]),){6}\*' in.txt > out.txt
```

Explanation: you first look the beginning of a line (`^`), followed by six successions of **either alphanumeric characters or an asterisk** followed by a comma (`(([[:alnum:]]+|[*]),)`; with `{6}` defining the number of repetitions), then check whether the next character is an asterisk. If yes, the matching line gets copied to `out.txt`.